# How do I export saved web pages from Chrome on Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, downloading, offline, export

I have a lot of sites saved for offline reading in Chrome.
Some of them aren't online anymore.
Is there a way to get them out of the app in HTML files?

Chrome version:  60.0.3112.116

Comment: I've googled this and I haven't found a solution. I'm sure the files are saved somewhere, but they're probably in some unreadable format. If nothing else works, print them as PDFs (share button -> print).